# My spreadsheet reading function constantly overwrites everything

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, spreadsheet

Okay so I have a spreadsheet and I want to put all the entries into my nested dictionary lists.
I decided to use two for loops to iterate through the spreadsheet. And safe the value of the cell to the according nested dictionary.
Here is my code (I know it's shit I'm pretty inexperienced):

```
def SpGetLink():
global SpDic
for row in SpDicGen():
    Data = dict.fromkeys(SpDic.values(), {})
    Data[SpDic[row]]["Link"] = []
    Data[SpDic[row]]["Title"] = []
    for col in range(1000):
        if ws.cell(row=row, column=col + 6).hyperlink is not None:
            data = str(ws.cell(row=row, column=col + 6).hyperlink.target)
            if data.startswith("http"):
                if data not in Data[SpDic[row]]["Link"]:
                    Data[SpDic[row]]["Link"].append(data)
                    json.dump(Data, open("Data.json", "w+"), indent=4)  # , sort_keys=True)
            else:
                Data[SpDic[row]]["Title"].append(data)
```

SpDic is a seperate Dictionary to get the corresponding Name to the row.

Now my Problem is the following.
When I open Data.json every list that should contain all links in the corresponding row contains the same  5 links which are the last 5 links the the spreadsheet. It looks something like this:

```
"smile": {
    "Link": [
        "https://media.giphy.com/media/k7J8aS3xpmhpK/giphy.gif",
        "https://media.giphy.com/media/aY1HMl4E1Ju1y/giphy.gif",
        "https://media.giphy.com/media/RLJxQtX8Hs7XytaoyX/giphy.gif",
        "https://media.giphy.com/media/1448TKNMMg4BFu/giphy.gif",
        "https://media.giphy.com/media/b7l5cvG94cqo8/giphy.gif"
    ],
    "Title": []
},
"grin": {
    "Link": [
        "https://media.giphy.com/media/k7J8aS3xpmhpK/giphy.gif",
        "https://media.giphy.com/media/aY1HMl4E1Ju1y/giphy.gif",
        "https://media.giphy.com/media/RLJxQtX8Hs7XytaoyX/giphy.gif",
        "https://media.giphy.com/media/1448TKNMMg4BFu/giphy.gif",
        "https://media.giphy.com/media/b7l5cvG94cqo8/giphy.gif"
    ],
    "Title": []
},
"laugh": {
    "Link": [
        "https://media.giphy.com/media/k7J8aS3xpmhpK/giphy.gif",
        "https://media.giphy.com/media/aY1HMl4E1Ju1y/giphy.gif",
        "https://media.giphy.com/media/RLJxQtX8Hs7XytaoyX/giphy.gif",
        "https://media.giphy.com/media/1448TKNMMg4BFu/giphy.gif",
        "https://media.giphy.com/media/b7l5cvG94cqo8/giphy.gif"
    ],
    "Title": []
},
```

Does anyone have an Idea why this is happening and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why your data is overwritten each time is because you are dumping your json inside the for loop. I moved it outside and I think this should do the trick.

```
def SpGetLink():
Data = []
global SpDic
for row in SpDicGen():
    Data = dict.fromkeys(SpDic.values(), {})
    Data[SpDic[row]]["Link"] = []
    Data[SpDic[row]]["Title"] = []
    for col in range(1000):
        if ws.cell(row=row, column=col + 6).hyperlink is not None:
            data = str(ws.cell(row=row, column=col + 6).hyperlink.target)
            if data.startswith("http"):
                if data not in Data[SpDic[row]]["Link"]:
                    Data[SpDic[row]]["Link"].append(data)
                    
            else:
                Data[SpDic[row]]["Title"].append(data)
with open("Data.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(Data, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But It didn't work. I have the same Problem when I just print Data at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by just making one of the for loops into a function and calling it in another for loop.